# How do I use the git commit id as a docker image tag in maven?

Tags: git, maven, docker

I'm trying to have docker images for a maven Java project built and pushed in the install and deploy phases respectively; and I'd like those images to be tagged with the current git commit id.

The problem that I am facing is that the [maven-git-commit-plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/) does not seem to export the `${git.commit.id.abbrev}` variable correctly for consumption in [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin).

My parent `pom.xml` goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    
    <name>myproject</name>

    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>mymodule</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>

        <!-- dependency versions -->    
           <!-- some stuff here...-->
        <!-- plugin versions -->
        <maven.enforcer.plugin.version>1.4.1</maven.enforcer.plugin.version>
        <maven.shade.plugin.version>2.4.2</maven.shade.plugin.version>
        <scala.maven.plugin.version>3.2.2</scala.maven.plugin.version>
        <com.spotify.docker.plugin.version>0.3.8</com.spotify.docker.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
           <!-- some stuff here...-->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${com.spotify.docker.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>docker-build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>docker-push</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>push</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <forceTags>true</forceTags>
                        <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>revision</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <configuration>
                        <dateFormatTimeZone>${user.timezone}</dateFormatTimeZone>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

And my plugins part of my module pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>docker-registry.nexus.bazaarvoice.com/${project.parent.artifactId}-${project.artifactId}:${git.commit.id.abbrev}</imageName>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory of the image -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>config</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/deploy/config/${project.artifactId}</directory>
                        <include>*</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.3.8:build (docker-build) on project service: Exception caught: The template variable 'git.commit.id.abbrev' has no value -> [Help 1]
```

I've tried switching to [buildnumber-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) but I get the same kind of error (using `${buildNumber}` instead of `${git.commit.id.abbrev}`).

What I am missing? Is the docker plugin executing before the git commit id plugin sets the variables?

Comment: By the way, I found this article where they seem to be doing exactly the same, but there are no mentions about the configuration of the git commit id plugin: https://www.alooma.com/blog/building-dockers

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem since I was invoking the plugin directly (I have not bound the plugin phases in my pom, so I have to invoke it explicitly):

```
mvn -f myModule/pom.xml docker:build -DforceTags -DpushImage
```

With the plugin conf:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <imageName>registry/myModule</imageName>
        <imageTags>
            <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
            <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
            <imageTag>${git.commit.id.abbrev}</imageTag>
        </imageTags>
        <baseImage>java</baseImage>
        <entryPoint>
            ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]
        </entryPoint>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Since the [maven-git-commit-plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/) is bound to the initialize phase, I had to invoke that phase so the git plugin populated the property

```
mvn initialize -f myModule/pom.xml docker:build -DforceTags -DpushImage
```

Comment: that didn't work, the resulting image was tagged simply as "latest" :-/

Comment: How are you launching the image generation? Can you provide the maven command you use to create it?

Answer (score 0):

try to use
`mvn package docker:build`
instead
`mvn docker:build`